# pagination is not working and redirect to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress blog that a Page choose front page (Home page),
when i select the Page as a home (from appearance -> read) pagination is not working and redirect to homepage.
that mean when enter this address: `example.com/page/2` it's redirect to `example.com`

i'm showing my recent posts with a shortcode that called in function.php
this is my shortcode:

```
function last_posts() {
$my_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-1&posts_per_page=5' );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

echo '<div style="margin: 20px 5px;" class="row post-inner-content">';
echo '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6" style="padding-right: 15px;">';
echo '<a class="recent-posts-title" href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
echo '<p class="recent-posts-date">'.get_the_date().'</p>';
echo '<p class="hidden-xs recent-posts-excerpt">';
echo kc_excerpt();
echo '</p>';
echo '<p class="recent-posts-cat">';

$cat = get_the_category($recent["ID"]); //get the category array
if ($cat[0]->name != "Featured") { //check if the category is "featured"
$catname = $cat[2]->name; //set $catname variable to "featured"
} else {
$catname = $cat[0]->name; //or set $catname variable to "other category name"
}
echo $catname; //output $catname variable


echo '</p>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array( 350, 220) ).'</a></div>';
echo '</div>';

endwhile;
}
add_shortcode( 'lastposts', 'last_posts' );
```

And i'm using [lastposts] shortcode in my home page (front page) for showing 5 recent posts.

how i can add pagination number in my shortcode and it's work.
and why pagination is not working?
sorry for my bad English
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code -

```
function last_posts() {

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

    echo '<div style="margin: 20px 5px;" class="row post-inner-content">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6" style="padding-right: 
    15px;">';
    echo '<a class="recent-posts-title" 
    href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
    echo '<p class="recent-posts-date">'.get_the_date().'</p>';
    echo '<p class="hidden-xs recent-posts-excerpt">';
    echo kc_excerpt();
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p class="recent-posts-cat">';

    $cat = get_the_category($recent["ID"]); //get the category array

    if ($cat[0]->name != "Featured") { //check if the category is "featured"
        $catname = $cat[2]->name; //set $catname variable to "featured"
    } else {
        $catname = $cat[0]->name; //or set $catname variable to "other 
    category 
    name"
    }
    echo $catname; //output $catname variable

    echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a 
    href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 
    array( 
    350, 220) ).'</a></div>';
    echo '</div>';

endwhile;

    // Pagination code           
    global $my_query;

    echo paginate_links( array(
     'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( 
      get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
     'total'        => $my_query->max_num_pages,
     'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
     'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
     'show_all'     => false,
     'type'         => 'plain',
     'end_size'     => 2,
     'mid_size'     => 1,
     'prev_next'    => true,
     'prev_text'    => '<span class="lnr lnr-arrow-left"></span>',
     'next_text'    => '<span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span>',
     'add_args'     => false,
     'add_fragment' => '',
   ) );          

}
add_shortcode( 'lastposts', 'last_posts' );
```

For more information please check this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: thanks but still it's not working and redirect to main page, i want when user open `example.com/page/2` open new tab that show 10 lasts posts.